# Docker container not updating from committed latest on gitlab

Tags: docker, gitlab

I’m new very to gitlab and have taken over someone else's work:

- Modify code using single file edit on gitlab
- Commit code on gitlab
- Run standard pipeline (maybe it goes wrong here?)
- Can see ‘latest’ in Docker container repository
- Do docker compose down/up on target system, permissions fine
- image yaml is gitlab.registryname etc **:latest**
- No error reported but update from code never reflected in container

This must be some simple noob mistake but what?

TIA Hugh

Comment: `update from code never reflected in container` So did you pull? Did you compare SHA of containers?

Comment: Thanks, I assumed, perhaps wrongly, that the docker compose up with latest would pull from the newly created container on gitlab?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_up/ -> --pull=always

Comment: Thanks again. Not on site now (no remote allowed), so I'll try this tomorrow and report on results, Looking at docker pull doc, hopefully this solves it!

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if this is the issue but in the steps you haven't mentioned `Docker pull`.

A Docker container is a runtime instance of a Docker image that gets created when the `$ docker run command` is implemented.

You mentioned Do `docker compose down/up on` target system, permissions fine, if compose.yml file doesn't `pull` the latest image which probably not cause the container isn't updated as you mentioned then you have to add a `docker pull` in your compose file or pull the newest image manually from the repository.

So your Docker container won't be updated unless you pull the latest image therefor it will create a new instance

Comment: Yes thanks. A separate pull seems to solve my problems, basically caused by a lack of experience with some of the finer points of Docker.